# Finding the x-intercept of a straight line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

My question today is whether or not the formula for the x-intersect has been discovered for any straight line on a graph.

I have been working on this for a bit and I think I have discovered a formula that may work to solve this problem. However, I'm not sure if it works for every single line. Of course, I'm not asking that you work this out because it would be a complete waste of your time but if you could try to use it with a few examples and tell me of your findings, I would be very grateful.

The formula, when the equation of a straight line is $y=mx + c$ where $mx$ is the gradient of the line and $c$ is the y-intercept, is $-c/m$ so the coordinates of the point would be ($-c/m$, $0$).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct (provided that $m \ne 0$ - horizontal lines may not ever meet the $x$-axis). You can verify by direct substitution:

$$y = m \left(\frac{-c}{m}\right) + c = -c + c = 0$$

after cancelling various terms.

Good find!

Comment: Hello, thank you for this post, however, it still doesn't answer my question of: has it been discovered. Thank you again!

Comment: @capturographer Yes, it is known. In fact, there are closed forms for the $x$-intercepts of polynomial equations of degree $1, 2, 3$, and $4$ (but for no higher order, which is a deep fact).

Comment: So this is actually a good find?

Comment: Yes, it's good that you found this on your own. It's been proven before, but this was still a good find.

Comment: Thank you again! I'm only a fifteen year old student and I am really looking forward (fingers crossed!) to a future career in mathematics. Any help is really appreciated.